# keep on min max while insert sort - linked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to insert nodes to linked list in sorted way, 
and keep on the TAIL of the list and the HEAD (which are the min and max)

this is my code:

```
void sortedInsert(AutoMotor **head, AutoMotor *new_car)
{
    AutoMotor* current;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->id >= new_car->id)
    {
        new_car->next = *head;
        *head = new_car;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = *head;
        while (current->next != NULL && current->next->id < new_car->id)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        int MAX = current->id;
        new_car->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_car;
    }
    printf("new car add successfully to M\n\n");
}
```

how can I extract the min & max (in O(1)) from this function(i would like to print them)?

THANK FOR YOUR HELP

Comment: the question still not very clear: are you trying to keep track on the min and max all the time OR you want to insert the nodes in a sorted manner, means that after each insertion of a node you're still having a sorted list?

Comment: keep on the min and max all the time and also insert the nodes in a sorted manner.

Comment: I got trouble with the implementation:                                                                       the max will defined like this:  max = current->next;                                          but how it promise me that this is the pointer for the tail of linked list

Comment: my problem is where and how to insert (and locate) the statement the keeping on MAXIMUM

Comment: do you have any restrictions on the time complexity of insertion?

Comment: Note: if the list is sorted, the max/min will be at the head/tail of the list. *or* the freshly inserted element, if it is inserted above the head, or under the tail, or both (if the initial list was empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add two parameters, for old min and old max (pointers or refs), and update them each time you insert.

Edited per liona comment:

```
void sortedInsert(AutoMotor **head, AutoMotor *new_car, AutoMotor **min, AutoMotor **max)
{
    AutoMotor* current;
    /* Special case for the head end */
    if (*head == NULL || (*head)->id >= new_car->id)
    {
        new_car->next = *head;
        *head = new_car;
        *min = *head;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Locate the node before the point of insertion */
        current = *head;
        while (current->next != NULL && current->next->id < new_car->id)
        {
            current = current->next;
        }
        //int MAX = current->id;
        new_car->next = current->next;
        current->next = new_car;
        if ( current->next == NULL )
        {
            *max = current;
        }
    }
    printf("new car add successfully to M\n\n");
}
```

Comment: may you help me, I have try to insert:                                                                                    if (current->next)
    {
     max = current;
    }                                                                                                 after the while loop, but it's not working, I forgot to say that my function get a pointer to the minimium

Answer (score 0):

According to the information which you provided in the question, the data structure which could help you best is AVL trees:
inserting a new value takes `O(log(n))` and so does deleting and finding it.
Moreover, you need to save that AVL tree on the side and each time you insert a new value to the tree, you add a new node to your linked list(so that the number of nodes in the linked list and the AVL tree is the same) and you simply do  `in order` traversal on the tree which in return gives you the values in a sorted manner in `O(n)`, means, inserting a new element and getting a sorted list takes `O(log(n)) + O(n) = O(n)`
in order to get the Min and Max in `O(1)` is now very easy if you can think about it(im sure you already figured it if you have the elements in a sorted manner).

[Here](https://github.com/ThunderWiring/CppGenericAVL) is an implementation for an AVL tree in C++ which i made few weeks ago, you can contact me regarding any questions about it